# Find all basis for a set V

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, change-of-basis

The set $V= \{ v_1, v_2,..., v_6 \}$ is represented by $V = \{ (1, 0, 2, 3), (4, 0, 8, 12), (4, 3, 2, 1), (4, 6, -4, -10), (1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 4, 3)$. Of course the set is in $\mathbb{R^4}$. Find all the bases that are subsets of V. First, to satisfy the condition for a basis, it first needs to be linearly independent. So should I make this into a matrix, and convert it to reduced row echelon? From there, I can found out which vector is linearly independent by looking at the pivot columns, which are guaranteed to be linearly independent by definition.

Comment: That seems fine. Is that your question?

Comment: if you check all $6 \choose 4$ you will have to check $15$ possible matrices which is a lot of work. You can start by noticing that $4v_1=v_2$ so any subset that contains those two will be linearly dependent. That already will eliminate $4\choose 2$ matrices that you need to consider

Comment: @aldodecristo Rather, if we drop $v_2$, we are left with $5\choose 4$ choices only but each basis involving $v_1$ gives rise to another basis involving $v_2$ instead. Row echelon of those 5 vectors can perhaps(!) immediately tell that eveys fourset out of these five is a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V = \{ v_1=(1, 0, 2, 3), v_2=(4, 0, 8, 12), v_3=(4, 3, 2, 1), v_4=(4, 6, -4, -10), v_5=(1, 1, 1, 1), v_6=(2, 1, 4, 3)\}$. Here I am using $[v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4]$ as the matrix generated by the row vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ (it could be column vectors, without prejudice to what you want). Doing the calculations, we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\det\,[v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4] &=& 0\\ 
\det\,[v_1, v_2, v_3, v_5] &=& 0\\
\det\,[v_1, v_2, v_3, v_6] &=& 0\\
\det\,[v_2, v_3, v_4, v_6] &=& -32\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Next, I am using the $\equiv$ symbol to indicate the (triangular) decomposition of the matrix.

The matrix $[v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4]$ has rank 2.

$$
[v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4] \equiv \left( \begin{array}{rrrr} 
1&0&2&3\\
0&3&-6&-11\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

The matrix $[v_1, v_2, v_3, v_5]$ has rank 3.

$$
[v_1, v_2, v_3, v_5] \equiv \left( \begin{array}{rrrr} 
1&0&2&3\\
0&3&-6&-11\\
0&0&1&\frac{5}{3}\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

The matrix $[v_1, v_2, v_3, v_6]$ has rank 3.

$$
[v_1, v_2, v_3, v_6] \equiv \left( \begin{array}{rrrr} 
1&0&2&3\\
0&3&-6&-11\\
0&0&2&\frac{2}{3}\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

The matrix $[v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5]$ has rank 3.

$$
[v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5] \equiv \left( \begin{array}{rrrr} 
4&0&8&12\\
0&3&-6&-11\\
0&0&1&\frac{5}{3}\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

The matrix $[v_2, v_3, v_4, v_6]$ has rank 3.

$$
[v_2, v_3, v_4, v_6] \equiv \left( \begin{array}{rrrr} 
4&0&8&12\\
0&3&-6&-11\\
0&0&2&\frac{2}{3}\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

The matrix $[v_3, v_4,v_5, v_6]$ has rank 4.

$$
[v_2, v_3, v_4, v_6] \equiv \left( \begin{array}{rrrr} 
4&3&2&1\\
0&3&-6&-11\\
0&0&1&\frac{5}{3}\\
0&0&0&-\frac{8}{3}\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Except for the $(v_3, v_4, v_5, v_6)$ combination, the other vector combinations are linearly independent, that is, they generate the $\mathbb{R}^4$ space.